# Calculate the norms: 1,2,$\infty$ of $A$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

A=$\begin{pmatrix} 2 \ -1 \\2 \ \ \ \ \ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$$\| A \|_1=\max_{j \in \{1,2\} } \  \sum_{i=1}^2 \lvert a_{ij} \lvert=4$$

$$\| A \|_\infty=\max_{i \in \{1,2\} } \  \sum_{j=1}^2 \lvert a_{ij} \lvert=3$$

$A^t A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \  2 \\-1 \ 0 \end{pmatrix} \ \begin{pmatrix} 2 \  -1 \\2 \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 8 \  -2 \\-2 \ \ \ \ \ \ 1 \end{pmatrix} $

Finding eigenvalues of $A^t \ A$:

$\det (A^t A - \lambda I_n)=\det \begin{pmatrix} 8-\lambda \ \ \ \ \ -2 \\ -2 \ \ \ \ 1-\lambda  \end{pmatrix}=(8-\lambda)(1-\lambda)-4$

$\lambda^2-9 \lambda +4=0$

$\lambda_1=\frac{9+\sqrt{65}}{2} $

$\lambda_2=\frac{9-\sqrt{65}}{2} $

So:

$\| A \|_2=\sqrt{\frac{9+\sqrt{65}}{2}}$

Is it correct?

Thanks

Comment: It looks fine !

Comment: Just for fun - in Geogebra create a unit circle (input Circle[(0,0),1]). Place a point B on the circle. Input  your matrix A = {{2,-1},{2,0}}. Input C = A*B to create a new point C on the screen. Right click C and select Trace On. Use the selection arrow to move point B round the circle, tracing out the path of C. The largest distance from the origin is your 2 norm of A. Input d = Length[C] and see how close you can get d to your norm value as you move B.